# Flutter How to get past purchases on Android with in_app_purchase: ^1.0.8

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-packages, android-inapp-purchase

I was using the **in_app_purchase** package old version but I have to upgrade it to **1.0.8**.

I was checking if the user has purchased the product by the code down below:

```
QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse response = await _iap.queryPastPurchases();
    setState(() {
      _purchases = response.pastPurchases;
    });
    print("PAST PURCHASES: $_purchases");
```

With 1.0.8, there is no queryPastPurchases method. We have `restorePurchases()`, so how can implement it to get old purchases to check if the user has already bought the product?

Thank you...